# `no such file or directory` While installing js beautify in npm

Tags: npm, js-beautify

I get this error when i use `npm -g install js-beautify`

```
npm ERR! path /home/developer/software/nodejs/lib/node_modules/js-
beautify/js/bin/css-beautify.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 
'/home/developer/software/nodejs/lib/node_modules/js-
beautify/js/bin/css-beautify.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/developer/.npm/_logs/2017-09-18T07_52_38_910Z-
debug.log
```

What can be done to  solve this?

I am using node 8.5.0 an npm 5.3.0

Comment: or Add the package-lock.json for temporary fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282382/1910007

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[JS-Beautify 1.7.0 is broken](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1247).

Explicitly install the last good version:

```
npm -g install js-beautify@1.6.14
```

… or wait for a fixed version to be released.

Comment: @Ragas this is because there's a breakage in the latest release of js-beautify FYI

Comment: installing it globally will probably broke another new project use this fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275969/npm-install-and-npm-run-dev-giving-error/46282382#46282382

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was to add to `package.json`:

`"devDependencies": {
    "js-beautify": "1.6.14",`

and

`"resolutions": {
    "js-beautify": "1.6.14"
  }`

then delete the `node_modules/` directory

and finaly reinstall all of the dependencies using `npm install` *(for some reason yarn would fail - even after deleting yarn.lock)*