# NPM install and npm run dev giving error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have installed package `npm i vue-admin-paper-dashboard`. 
And after that when I run
`npm install` I am getting below error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path E:\xampp\htdocs\VUEjs Templates\VUEjs-1\vue-paper-dashboard\node_modules\js-beautify\js\bin\css-beautify.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'E:\xampp\htdocs\VUEjs Templates\VUEjs-1\vue-paper-dashboard\node_modules\js-beautify\js\bin\css-beautify.js'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'E:\xampp\htdocs\VUEjs Templates\VUEjs-1\vue-paper-dashboard\node_modules\js-beautify\js\bin\css-beautify.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

And when I run `npm run dev`, I am getting below error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! vue-admin-paper-dashboard@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env ENABLE_ESLINT=true node build/dev-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-admin-paper-dashboard@1.0.0 dev script 'cross-env ENABLE_ESLINT=true node build/dev-server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vue-admin-paper-dashboard package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     cross-env ENABLE_ESLINT=true node build/dev-server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs vue-admin-paper-dashboard
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls vue-admin-paper-dashboard
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.<br />
```

**NOTE:** I have installed cross-env package globally.

**EDIT:**
I have tried cloning the project: [LINK](https://github.com/cristijora/vue-paper-dashboard.git), and then run `npm install` still I am getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS-Beautify 1.7.0 is broken, version 1.6.14 must work:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46275582/2953376 
https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/1247

Answer (score 1):

to fix the JS-Beautify 1.7.0 be sure you are using the node version >= 8. add the package-lock.json in the project root

add the version of JS-Beautify in the "dependencies" like this: 
 `{
  "name": "my project name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "js-beautify": {
      "version": "1.6.14",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/js-beautify/-/js-beautify-1.6.14.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-07j3Mi0CuSd9WL0jgmTDJ+WARM0=",
      "dev": true
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing using flags `--save` or `--save-dev`?

Comment: I am installing just one package npm i vue-admin-paper-dashboard and this I have installed using --save flag